# Symfony 2 can't do single console command and no proper error

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I've been working quite a while on a Symfony2 project and it looks very nice.
However, to save some time lately I've been programming a lot without actually testing the functionality. Obviously I didn't push it to the live environment either.

Now I'm trying to start the built-in PHP server to run my project locally to see what I broke by coding blindly and ... well, I must've broken something BIG.

```
app/console server:start
```

Hangs for a few seconds and finally I get an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

That's it. There's literally nothing more in the console. It doesn't say where I made a mistake, whether it's in my code (no class names, no lines) or somewhere else... This is like a needle in a haystack.

I've tried running it with the **--force** flag because it's just a warning, maybe it could continue and crash again later (and give me a proper reason why then), but I get the same error.

All the other command like trying to clear the cache, trying to validate my doctrine schema's etc. produce the exact same result. Nothing in the logs either. Not even in /var/logs/apache2.

I've manually cleared the cache and try to run the server again to see if maybe it would show me a different error. It does manage to create a folder structure:

```
.
└── dev
    ├── annotations
    ├── classes.map
    ├── jms_aop
    ├── jms_security
    └── serializer
```

But doesn't manage to place anything inside these folders. So I think I'm getting the error rather quickly.

I'm looking for a needle in a haystack over here... I've looked through my code, figuring out if I made a stupid mistake in my foreach loops but I don't see anything.

Is there any way I can get more debugging information from Symfony? A simple class name or line would help me figure out what the underlying cause might be but this is just madness. I don't even have a clue where to start.

**UPDATE:**

@JimL pointed out to me that I could increase the verbosity level of the console command output.

By adding **-vvv** to the output I managed to get a full stack trace of the exception. Once I saw the last line:

```
/Users/A Sneaky Ginger/path/to/my/project/vendor/jms/serializer-bundle/JMS/SerializerBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterEventListenersAndSubscribersPass.php:48
```

at first I was confused because this isn't a file which I've edited myself. But after a few head scratches I could figure out that one of my EventListeners had the code:

```
static public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    //return array(
        //array("event" => "serializer.post_serialize", "class" => "Acme\myBundle\Entity\myEntity", "method" => "onPostSerialize")
    //);
}
```

Which was causing the invalid parameter given to the foreach().
I still think a small hint could've been included by default in the warning message because this was really too vague, but luckily JimL saved the day.

Comment: When you use the CLI you're not using Apache so no errors should end up there. You could change the verbosity level http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#verbosity-levels

Comment: @JimL I must've read over this. By adding **-vvv** after the command I got a full stack trace. I still can't make sense of the issue but that's another problem - so I'll create another question for it. Can you write your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the CLI you're not using Apache so no errors should end up there. You could change the verbosity level
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#verbosity-levels